# Paginate Custom Json

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF in my API's, and I got a situation, I create a view "APIView" and then I cant paginate it.

I did before many custom pagination but in my case, I can't find the solution and takes from me many hours. So please anyone can help me, and guide me to the solution.

BTW, I read DRF documentation and I found this and also I can't do that. I found: "Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic views or viewsets. If you're using a regular APIView, you'll need to call into the pagination API yourself to ensure you return a paginated response."

here is my `views.py` code

```
class MyInboxAPIView(APIView):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    def get(self, request):

        single_inbox = ChatRoom.objects.filter(Q(first_user=self.request.user) | Q(second_user=self.request.user)).distinct()
        single_inbox_count = single_inbox.count()
        my_teams = Team.objects.filter(players=self.request.user)
        team_inbox = TeamMessage.objects.filter(team__in=my_teams).order_by().values_list('team').distinct()
        team_inbox_count = team_inbox.count()
        my_inbox_teams = Team.objects.filter(pk__in=team_inbox)
        contact = []
        teams = []


        for i in single_inbox:
            if i.first_user == self.request.user:
            contact.append({"name": i.second_user.first_name + ' ' + i.second_user.last_name,  "room_id": i.pk})
        elif i.second_user == self.request.user:
            contact.append({"name": i.first_user.first_name + ' ' + i.first_user.last_name, "room_id": i.pk})
        for i in my_inbox_teams:
            teams.append({"name": i.name, "team_id": i.pk})

        my_inbox = {"inbox": {"single chat": [{'contact': contact}], "team chat": [{'team': teams}]},
                "number of single chats": single_inbox_count, "number ofteam chats": team_inbox_count}

        return Response(my_inbox)
```